# Cakephp3 odd behavior with external link that has https in url parameters (first https gets remove)

Tags: url, cakephp, https, parameters, cakephp-3.0

Ok I'm trying using LinkedIn's api and when I build out a sample call, example below

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin&state=987654321">Login</a>
```

It displays like this on the front end of cakephp 3, the first https is getting striped away

```
<a href="/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&amp;client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin&state=wGg4ksv8WHpx26dV">Login in</a>
```

As soon as I remove the `https` from the redirct_uir parameter or the whole `redirct_uri` parameter it display currently. Anyone know how to fix this or a good work around. I need have a https in both urls for the api to work correctly.

Comment: So far all I have come up with is to inject the anchor link after the page load using javascript. It works but not how I would like to do it.
 `<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$('.legal').append('<a href=\"https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin&state=987654321\">Login in</a>');
  
});
</script>`
Hope some one has a fix or better work around

Comment: Maybe show some of the code you're using to "build out a sample call"? I noticed that the state is different in the two URLs you show, is that just a copy-paste thing, or is the actual state in the final result different than you expect it to be? If the latter, the problem may be somewhere else entirely.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I think the browser is stripping the `https`. He's using invalid characters in the query part.

Answer (score 2):

You are using invalid characters in your query parameters. I'm going to guess that the browser is stripping the `https` since there are `://` characters after the `?` query identifier.

You have to call `urlencode("https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin")` and use the result as the query parameter.